# c# streamreader string that begin with

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am new to C#. I try to parse a text file using the `StreamReader` class:

```
1,0
BRD1,100 - 2017.02.24-12.26 - SaraH
BRD2,HDF-101D-BL3M,2800,2070,100,0,3,HDF-101D-BL3M,,,0,,0,,
XBRD1,100 - 2017.02.24-12.26 - SaraH
XBRD2,100 - 2017.02.24-12.26 - SaraH/0001,2800,270.8,1,0,3,HDF-101D-BL3M,,,0,,1,,

PNL1,100 - 2017.02.24-12.26 - SaraH
PNL2,1,HDF-101D-BL3M,1130,295,2,0,,,,,1,0,0,PIL_100_1130x295.bmp
PRM2,21,0,50,50,0,0,0,80,80,80
PRM3,18,0,0,15,15,15,75,1,200,2,350,3,650,4,1050,5,0,6,2600,7,4200,8,0,9,0,10,0,11,0,12,0,13,0,14,0,15,0,16,0,17,0,18

MAT2,HDF-101D-BL3M,HDF 101D white h-3mm,3,0,2,4.8,4.8,4.8,0,0,0,15,15,15,15,5,5,5,0,250,250,0.06,0,60,2200,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,30,30,30,17,NTMDPI,0,19,9.51,0.03,2,11.59,0.03,2,2,0,0:11,,,,,,,,,,RGB(255:255:255),

PTN2,1,,1,1,4:38,0:04,5,11,0,0
PTNR,(((5!),X2),((7!),(9),(9),(9)),(3!,2!))

INFO1,100 - 2017.02.24-12.26 - SaraH,100 - 2017.02.24-12.26 - SaraH,standart15,HP30
INFO4,2
CHK1,9183
```

I need to get a string there is after `BRD1, MAT2, INFO4`
also

```
100 - 2017.02.24-12.26 - SaraH    --> to label1
HDF-101D-BL3M,HDF 101D white-3mm  --> to label2
2                                 --> to label3
```

At the moment, I try to choose only the right lines and then split.

Because `if (line.Contains(word))` choose all lines which contain this string, I need something like `line.BeginWith(word)`.

Also, if someone can help me, or can introduce me, if there is a better way to get this result.

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    string line;
    string[] words = { "BRD1", "MAT2", "INFO4"};
    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.FullPath))
    {
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                if (line.Contains(word))
                {
                    string[] fields = line.Split(',');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `line.StartsWith(word)`?

Comment: Instead of split you can also do `var restOfLine = line.Substring(word.Length, line.length - word.length);` That way you are not relying on the ',' and also you won't split the rest of the line into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a much more efficient way using [regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse the full text at once.

```
List<string> labels = new List<string>();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\r\n(BRD1|MAT2|INFO4),([^(,|\r\n)]*,?[^(,|\r\n)]*)");
using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.FullPath))
{
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(file.ReadToEnd()))
    {
        labels.Add(match.Groups[2].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This work fine, but on line MAT2 it put all from the line, and i need just the string between comma also DF-101D-BL3M,HDF 101D white-3mm

Comment: Would it always be the first two "words" seperated by a comma after MAT2 ?

Comment: yes, from all (BRD1,MAT2,INFO4) i need only the "second string" separated by comma. Like i wrotte beffore above (where is the label1,2,3)

Comment: I've edited the answer. The regular expression will now take at most the first two words after the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.StartsWith`:

```
foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (line.StartsWith(word))
    {
        string[] fields = line.Split(',');
    }
}
```

As an additional simplification, you can avoid the `forach` loop with the LINQ method `Enumerable.Any`:

```
if (words.Any(word => line.StartsWith(word)))
{
    string[] fields = line.Split(',');
}
```